# In pine language how to express a bar is finished and a new bar starts because I want to draw new lines once a new bar starts?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, line-drawing

Let me give an example demand:
I want to draw 2 horizontal lines which are based on the last bar once a new bar starts. One line is last bar's high price and the other line is its low price.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="testing", overlay=true)

var line pressure = na
var line support  = na

if(?????)   //I don't know in pine language how to express a bar is finished and a new bar starts. 
   pressure = line.new(bar_index-1, high[1], bar_index+9, high[1], color = color.red, width=1)
   support = line.new(bar_index-1, low[1], bar_index+9, low[1], color = color.green, width=1)
```

I want the below result(the 2 lines are drawn by me manually for explanation):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyVsK.png)

I think my code logic is correct but I just don't know how to express a bar is finished and a new bar starts. Or else is there any other way to achieve the same demand?

And one more result I want is to show the price numbers on the 2 lines just like the tradingview built-in Fibonacci retracement lines which shows both lines and price numbers:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLnKA.png)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use barstate to draw a line on a bar when it closes (this does not draw a line on a bar unless it just closed):

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Testing", overlay=true)

var line redLine = na
var line greenLine = na

if barstate.islast
    redLine := line.new(bar_index - 1, high[1], bar_index, high[1], width=1, color=color.red)
    greenLine := line.new(bar_index - 1, low[1], bar_index, low[1], width=1, color=color.green)
```

This produces this picture with lines on the previous bar:

[image]

As for the "Fibonacci" part, are you sure thats what you want? If you just want a line that connects the bottom of a bar to the top of another bar, you can use this:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Testing", overlay=true)

if barstate.islast and bar_index >= 3
    line.new(bar_index - 4, high[4], bar_index, low, width=1, color=color.blue)
```

Which produces this overlay on the chart:

[image]

Comment: Thank you bro. I use "bar_index+9" because I want the line length to be 10, hahaha. And your method of using barstate  works well.

Comment: Thank you bro. I use "bar_index+9" because I want its length to be 10. And barstate  works well. Can I ask you one more question: I want to select a bar's low point to another bar's high point and then it draws 2 lines, which is similar like tradingview's built-in Fibonacci retracement lines, only the calculation method is different(for example one line is "region low+0.3*(region close-region open )" and the other one is "region high-0.3*(region close-region open )"). and also need it show the line's price value. Thank you for your time to answer me !

Comment: I tested your method on tradingview and found one problem: I want to draw line based on last bar which is already finished, but your code logic will draw line based on current bar which is still running.

Comment: I can get back to you sometime tomorrow. Sorry that it wasn't what you wanted, but happy to help and fix it.

Comment: plz don't say that bro. The "barstate.islast" already helped me a lot. Can u help me check how to select start point(one bar's low) and end point(another bar's high), and then draw lines ?(which I have asked in above comment). Thank you!

Comment: I updated my post again with the second part. Please clarify with a picture of what you're expecting if this is not what you want

Comment: yup, I already "accepted" your answer. Actually I am not a professional programmer and also don't know stackoverflow's function very well, hahaha.

Comment: since i can't post code or picture in comment, so I will ask a new question for this matter. can you please go to my main page and check my new question so that you will understand my meaning better.

Comment: i have just posted a new question, can you go through it whenever u r free? thank you.